# Turn dissolved polygons to singlepart in geopandas?

Tags: python, dissolve, geopandas, singlepart

I have performed a dissolve but I want to turn it to singlepart.I have searched in the docs but haven't seen something that does it.
What do you think?

Actually, I want to make it singlepart and then create a column that will have something like `id` so later that I will be doing an intersection I will be using this `id` to remember the polygons that were as one and do a condition that keeps the max area.

The important thing here is how to turn it to singlepart and maybe how to approach the column with the `id` thinking.

```
data = dat[dat['TYPE'].str.startswith(('01'))]
dslved=data.dissolve(by=TYPE')

# here needs to be the singlepart process

interscted=gpd.overlay(dslved,file_m,how='intersection')
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems it has been solved by Philipp Schwarz on github :

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd

gpdf = gp.read_file('Germany/vg2500_bld.shp')

def multi2single(gpdf):
    gpdf_singlepoly = gpdf[gpdf.geometry.type == 'Polygon']
    gpdf_multipoly = gpdf[gpdf.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon']

    for i, row in gpdf_multipoly.iterrows():
        Series_geometries = pd.Series(row.geometry)
        df = pd.concat([gp.GeoDataFrame(row, crs=gpdf_multipoly.crs).T]*len(Series_geometries), ignore_index=True)
        df['geometry']  = Series_geometries
        gpdf_singlepoly = pd.concat([gpdf_singlepoly, df])

    gpdf_singlepoly.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return gpdf_singlepoly
```

Ref. : https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/369

Comment: I have already seen that but I don't know how to apply it to my data

Answer (score 4):

Create a column with a list of each multipolygons parts and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to rows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/my_sample.shp")

dissolved = df.dissolve(by="type") #This creates multipart geometries

#Create a column with all multipolygon polygons as a list
dissolved["singleparts"] = dissolved.apply(lambda x: [p for p in x.geometry.geoms], axis=1) 

# dissolved.singleparts.iloc[0]
# [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7ff264462c40>,
#  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7ff2644621c0>,
#  ...]

exploded = dissolved.explode("singleparts") #List to rows
exploded = exploded.set_geometry("singleparts")
del(exploded["geometry"])
exploded = exploded.rename_geometry("geometry")
```